# How to use dimensions variables of an array in some other function definition if they are entered via stdin in main?

Tags: c, arrays

If we are declaring an array `A[a][b]` globally outside `main()` and inside main we are asking for values of `a` and `b` as

```
scanf("Input values of a and b %d %d", &a,&b)
```

but this a and b are being used by some other function definition, it would give segmentation fault

Comment: You'll have to dynamically allocate memory to do this. Look into `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: but even then how can I use value of m in some other function like matrix multiply in above code. Like I did this in main                                                   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  first = malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
  for ( i =0;i <m; i++)
 A[i] =malloc(n*sizeof(int));

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want to have an array whose dimension is specified by the user at run time.  The best way to do this in c is to malloc a pointer:

```
int* A = malloc(a*b*sizeof(int));
```

A now points to an array with a*b elements in it, which you can view as a 2d array.

Comment: To treat it as a two-dimensional array, instead of using `int *A`, use `int (*A)[b] = malloc(a * sizeof *A);`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you want to allocate space for an array A of dimensions a and b, use:

```
int (*A)[b] = malloc(a * sizeof *A);
```

That defines A to be a pointer to rows (arrays) of `b` elements (`int` elements) and allocates space for `a` such rows (so `a` rows of `b` `int` objects, so `a*b` `int` objects).

In a function that you want to receive this array, declare the function this way:

```
void foo(size_t a, size_t b, int (*A)[b])
{
    …
}
```

That says that the parameters to foo are a size `a`, a size `b`, and a pointer to rows of `b` `int` objects.

Call the function like this:

```
foo(a, b, A);
```

Use the elements of `A` in the normal way:

```
…A[i][j]…
```

Comment: @user2079986: That creates pointers to pointers, which is unnecessary and generally requires accesses to the array to include an additional pointer look-up, which is typically slower. Making a single allocation with enough space for the entire array and accessing it through a pointer to an array is typically faster and, once the declarations are written, more intuitive.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain it with code I have added , I am taking input m and n which are dimensions of an array then allocating memory for it in main(). Then I have used m in a loop in a fuction outside main, how can i make m accessible in other function. Even when I use just pointer *A instead of **A

Comment: @user2079986: It is generally bad practice to use global variables. You can simply pass the pointer to the thread, along with the other data you are already passing. Instead of passing a structure that contains only the row and column information, pass a structure that contains all the information the thread needs, including the pointer to the matrix. However, since the structure needs to be declared in advance, you may need to make it a `void *` in the structure and then cast it to `int (*)[b]` inside the function in the thread.